# How To data bind the DropDownlist and Checkbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in data where i have add  assign work link.... when click on that it takes me to a assinedwork button where i dropdownlist bind the data in projectName  ...and like checkbox...

```
Table for Projects
-----------

ProjetsId  |  ProjectName  |Decscription..
 1         |    aaaa       |    hihihihi
 2         |   bbbb         |  helohelo

 like that .....
 to bind the project name to Dropdownlist.

Table for Employee
-------------------
EmployeeId  |  EmployeNameName  |EmployeDescription..
 1         |    aaaa            |    hihihihi
 2         |   bbbb             |  helohelo

to bind the EmployeName to Checkbox
please help me .....................
```

Comment: I don't understand how you can bind employeename to checkbox

Comment: @Mark.. In EmployeName  front of CheckBox when i click the checkbox insert to the datbase....

Answer (score 0):

**Binding to DropDownList**

Basically you have to create an enumerable collection of `SelectListItem` and pass it to the controller either through **ViewBag** or **View Model**.

From the action,

```
public ViewResult Edit(int id)
{
   ...

   var projects = _repository.GetAllProjects().Select(p => 
                     new SelectListItem
                     {
                        Text = p.ProjectName,
                        Value = p.ProjectsId.ToString()
                     });

   ViewBag.Projects = projects; // you can also use viewmodel

   ...
}
```

From the view,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProjectId, ViewBag.Projects, "Choose a project")
```